# Listview scroll bottom to top lag issue in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My listview scroll is working smooth,but after enable PullToRefresh to True then listview scroll from bottom to top is not properly working.

top to bottom scroll is working smothly but bottom to top scroll lags(stop) found.

here is my listview

```
<ListView x:Name="orderList" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorColor="Gray"
                          SeparatorVisibility="None" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding OrdDate}"
                          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OrderList_ItemSelected" 
                          ItemAppearing="OrderList_ItemAppearing" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="{Binding PullRefreshOrders}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoadingOrders}">
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="15">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding OrdDate}" TextColor="#3c454c" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <cv:OrderContentView/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please add some codes or share a sample with this problem? We can't do any help without seeing the codes.

Comment: @Jack Hua I updated my code.

Comment: Is lags happen when you pull to refresh? Can you share the of  `PullRefreshOrders`?

Comment: Pull refresh working fine,and the scroll also working smoothly,but when I go to top of items on which I already scroled(means bottom to top items) that time scroll is not properly work.If I scroll slow the it works,but if I scroll faster then scroll not works.

Comment: This works well before add `PullToRefresh`? While I don't think PullToRefresh will affect the scroll behavior of a listView. How about change the CachingStrategy to RetainElement?

Comment: RetainElement also not solve this issue.

Comment: No idea about what happened in your listView. Can you share a demo with this problem so that I can test it for you.

Comment: Is that the problem is on Emulator or Physical device?

Comment: I am running my app on a physical device

Answer (score 0):

this issue happen with my in listview and i change the PullToRefresh by syncfusion

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/pull-to-refresh

and it's work fine with me